# Using front matter data in Liquid tags

Tags: liquid, eleventy

I have a project in eleventy using Liquid for templates. It includes an image gallery which uses the official plugin for responsive images, invoked through a shortcode for generating the image markup with the following arguments:

```
{% for p in collections.projects %}
   {% for i in p.data.images %}
      {% image i, "alt text", "output path", "class list", "sizes" %}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(the line beginning with "{% image ..." is the actual shortcode function)

As long as I provide the arguments "manually", with only the iterator variable (i) coming from the for statement, everything works okay. However, there are instances where I need to obtain the image path, alt text or output path from the front-matter of a markdown content file. In this case, I wanted to not iterate through the images of project p, but rather just get the first one in the array using p.data.images[0].

I first tried the most straightforward approach

```
{% image p.data.images[0], p.data.alts[0] , p.data.outs[0], "class list", "sizes" %}
```

But that didn't work, and gave me an invalid syntax error instead (pointing at the first argument).

I also tried setting variables in preceding statements, like this:

```
{% assign path = p.data.path %}
{% assign img = p.data.images[0] %}
{% image img, "alt text", path, "class list", "sizes" %}
```

But this gives me an error stating that "src" (the first positional argument in the shortcode) is required. And I know the data for p.data.path and p.data.images[0] is there because I can print it just fine as an object like this:

```
{{ p.data.path }}
{{ p.data.images[0] }}
```

So what am I doing wrong here? There must be a way I can access my front matter data in these Liquid tags right? Why can I not do the following for example:

```
{% for p in collections.projects %}
   {% image p.data.images[0], p.data.alts[0], p.data.outs[0], "class list", "sizes" %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do all the pages in the collection have the `images` key set in the front matter?

Comment: @person_v1.32 I did try enclosing the shortcode in an if statement before, but I guess not with the assign tags to define variables. That actually solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

As hinted in comment by @person_v1.32, the issue was that not all elements of my collection had defined the accessed fields. So what I was attempting to do was solved by adding an if statement surrounding the shortcode, as follows:

```
  {% for p in collections.projects %}
    {% if p.data.images and p.data.path %}
      {% assign img = p.data.images[0] %}
      {% assign path = p.data.path %}
      {% image img, "alt", path, "class", "" %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```